# collapsable toolbar like whatsapp in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am new in react native i want to implement collapsing toolbar like whatsapp feature with those tools like search, settings, etc. For scrollable tab-bar i am using [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/blob/master/example/src/ScrollViewsExample.js). I searched a lot but yet i not get any comfortable example with that. Is there any example available? so i can implement that feature in my project.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have searched and didn't find anything, then you may create it yourself.
For instance, let's say you want to reproduce exactly the same behavior as Android Whatsapp, in this case you will need something like:

`<View>` to hold your content

`<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` to call your openMenu method

`<Icon>` with something like fontawesome to add the vertically dots

`<View>` another one to hold your options

`<TouchableHighlight>` to call your onItemPress method

`<Text>` to hold your texts

And your work will be styling it with flexbox, transition and opacity to make it looks like  what you want.

If you find that this component can be reused in more than one place in your project, then you can create it in a separated file like toolbar.js to export it and then import wherever you need like

```
import Toolbar from './toolbar'
...
render() {
...
<Toolbar />
...
}
```

For more information about everything I mentioned you can check the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

From there you can learn about all components I mentioned, tips of how to style it and how to export/import components.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i will try with this method.